# How to pass Multiple input array element values

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

As you can see I have a `for` loop with Multiple `ID` and I want get the value of `IDs` and pass them to my controller, how can I achieve this ?

```
<form id="UserEdit">
         @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Rights.Count; i++)
          { 
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Rights[i].ID)
          }

       <input id="BtnEditUserJS" onclick="PostFormUserEdit();" type="submit" value="Edit">
 </form>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<input id="Rights_0__ID" name="Rights[0].ID" type="hidden" value="31">

<input id="Rights_1__ID" name="Rights[1].ID" type="hidden" value="32">
```

JavaScript:

```
function PostFormUserEdit() {  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("EditUser")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ,
        success: function (run) {
            console.log('Ok');
            },
        error: function () {
          console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
            }
        });
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult EditUser(int[] RightId)
    {
        var rights = db.Rights.Where(b => RightId.Contains(b.Id)).ToList();

       //do something with rights
    }
```

Comment: Serializing the form should do that...

Comment: @mplungjan what if i want pass as parameter ?!

Comment: You need to NOT use onclick but instead `$(function() $("#UserEdit").on("submit",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("EditUser")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize() , ...`

Comment: @mplungjan when i use serialize my RightId becomes to null in controller and 
 as you see  my action singature wating/accept to get RightId as parameter.

Comment: If the values never change, you could just convert your list to JSON in the code behind and put the resulting string in the view inside a <script> tag. That way, your data will already be ready to be sent. Also, if you have a submit with an onclick, it will try to do both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it this way :

```
function PostFormUserEdit() 
{  
    var arr = [];
    $("#UserEdit input[type='hidden']").each(function (index, obj) {
        arr.push(obj.val());
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("EditUser")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: arr ,   // or you can try data: JSON.stringify(arr)
        success: function (run) {
            console.log('Ok');
            },
        error: function () {
          console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
            }
        });
}
```